Custom skill integration
I have a requirement to crawl an Azure SQL server from Azure AI search. The SQL server exists in different VNET and I have created a Shared Private Link to connect. The Indexer works fine without any problem.
As soon as I add a custom webapi skill the indexer starts complaining with an error

Cannot open server 'sqls-XXX-dev' requested by the login. Client with
IP address '51.XXX.XXX.140' is not allowed to access the server.

Can anyone kindly explain what am I doing wrong?
Integrate Custom Skill with SQL Server with Shared Private Access. The SQL server has not public IP enabled.

You get this error because the SQL server does not have a public IP enabled. You also mentioned that it works without a custom web API skill. However, once you add the skill, it raises the error, meaning the IP address of the function you are using has not been added to the SQL server network firewall rules.
To resolve this issue, you need to add the IP address to the firewall rules or create a firewall rule for this IP address or address range.

Also, check this documentation for Azure Private Link.

@Som Check if above provided solution works for you? Let me know if I can be helpful here anyway with further input?
